# How to update INI file that is marked as read-only (WiX toolset)

Tags: wix

I have a small installer project in Wix Toolset. One of the INI files I need to modify might be marked as read-only and the installer refuses to modify it.

[image: installer error]

Is there any way to force installer to do the INI modification? All I found was [permission setting](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/permission.html) during file installation, however this file is not part of the installation.

My component looks like this:

```
<Component Id="FooBar.ini" Guid="GUID" KeyPath="yes" Permanent="yes">
    <IniFile Id="FooBar.ini" Directory="FOOBARDIR" Name="FooBar.ini"
             Action="addLine" Section="Foo" Key="Bar" Value="1" />
</Component>
```

Comment: Have you tried a deferred custom action?

Comment: @mhs And what should I do in that action? Can you be more specific (I am a bit noobish with MSI)?

Comment: WIX custom action can execute with admin privileges as long as the execute method need to be deferred. If you implement a custom action to edit a ini file you might get to you target. 
Custom action can be C# or C++ dll or a Script or a shell command 

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/authoring_custom_actions.html

Or you can change the file permission by a custom action and let WIX to edit the INI.  

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html